# Reputation line chart on the activity graph seems to have changed recently

Tags: support, reputation-graph

I noticed today that the reputation line graph on the Activity tab of my Stack Overflow profile seems to have changed recently:

[image: Reputation graph]

I believe that previously it showed only the recent year (2 years?) but not anything earlier.  Now, it is showing my entire reputation history from when I first joined back in 2014.

Is there a reason for this change, and is it possible to control what the domain of this chart is myself?

Comment: no change at my end

Comment: Nope, the graph has always been like that. I don't see anything special. And no, there are no knobs for us to twiddle to change what is shown.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is not what I am used to seeing.  I am used to seeing a single upsloping line for the last 12 months or so.  Maybe I have been staring into a laptop for too many hours...

Comment: Will these help? https://web.archive.org/web/20170609003840/http://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen?tab=topactivity and https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users/2356/?tab=topactivity

Comment: @Pang Thanks for those links, and the first one looks like what I am used to, namely a 12 month x axis.

Comment: Maybe it shows a 4-year view as long as you joined 4 years or more ago?

Comment: As a note, your profile says you joined late in 2012, not in 2014. Mathematically speaking, 2014 wouldn't make since as the year you started, anyway. (My own graph only shows a few months, not years. But I found a user at 4 years 8 months with a graph like mine, so I have no idea what the trigger is.)